# What is the music on season 3 episode 21 of My Hero Academia around 6:20?

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

What is the music on season 3 episode 21  of My Hero Academia around 6:20?

Answer (score 0):

The soundtrack is called Hero A, here's the link: [Hero A](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9UPuhEonPdo) and here's the link to the instrumental if the rap isn't up your speed: [Hero A instrumental](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SkZ9jbw5kCc)